# Specify Region for Export Table in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a [dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WCMC_WDPA_current_polygons) of polygons for the entire planet that I'd like to export into a KML/KMZ file. However, I only need the data for South America. Is is possible to specify which regions to export?

This is the code I currently have:

```
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons');

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: polygons,
  folder: 'GEE_exports',
  fileFormat: 'KMZ'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw a polygon around South America, or use an additional dataset of simplified country shapefiles for South America. The latter is done below. Use `filterBounds()` to filter on only the polygons of the featureCollection within South America:

```
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons');
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var southAmericaLSIB = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('wld_rgn', 'South America'))
var southAmerica = polygons.filterBounds(southAmericaLSIB.geometry())

Map.addLayer(southAmericaLSIB, {color: 'red'})
Map.addLayer(southAmerica, {color: 'green'})
```

You can then export the filtered featureCollection as you did. [Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f88dffed25929c7fe6fee24f0d264aa)